iptables prerouting ignores traffic
I'm trying to prerouting port webserver via IPv6 without sucessfully.
I'm having this.
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 2604:a080:xxxx:xx::xxxx:1002 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to fd10:8:0:1::2

or
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 2604:a080:xxxx:xx::xxxx:1002 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to fd10:8:0:1::2

But only works if specify interface.
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to fd10:8:0:1::2

I have same configuration with iptables and works with specify destination host.
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 199.xxx.xxx.10 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.10.0.2

What i'm doing wrong? how i can specify incoming IPv6 address. The interface eth0 have multiple IPv6 address and i don't want forward all IPv6 have interface eth0.
